# Rewriting the equation governing local transport into $\nabla (\ln(\sigma)) \cdot \nabla U_0 =− \nabla ^2(U_0)$

Tags: condensed-matter, voltage, locality

A paper concerning local sheet conductivity and sheet current density says the equation governing local transport $$\nabla \cdot \vec{j} = − \nabla\cdot(\sigma \nabla U) = 0,$$ where U denotes the local transport potential, can be rewritten as $$\nabla (\ln \sigma) \cdot \nabla U_0 =− \nabla ^2(U_0),$$ where $U_0$ is the local transport voltage measured for a single configuration of the applied current. 
I am wondering how this second equation could be derived.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematics - it works in titles as well.  Also a link to at least the abstract page for a referenced paper is expected where possible.

Comment: edited! thank you.

Comment: Is [this preprint on Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4540) the paper you mentioned in your original version of the question ?

Comment: Your r.h.side is tensorial nonsense! You’ve skipped a gradient inside the parenthesis.

Comment: @StephenG Yes that's it

Comment: @CosmasZachos Can you explain how this is wrong? Would $\nabla (\ln \sigma) \cdot \nabla U_0 =− \nabla ^2 U_0$ solve it?

Comment: Your first equation is nonsense. The left is scalar, the right is vector.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Oh You're right My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain differentiating,
$$
\nabla\cdot (\sigma \nabla U)= \nabla \sigma \cdot \nabla U + \sigma \nabla^2 U,
$$
so equating to zero amounts to
$$
\frac{\nabla \sigma}{\sigma} \cdot \nabla U =-  \nabla^2 U .$$